# Truncate all digits of an integer except the first two

Tags: c++

For example:

```
int input;
cout << "Please enter how many burgers you'd like" << endl;
cin >> input;
```

What would be the easiest way to shorten 'input' and only accept the first two <strike>bits</strike> digits.
To continue the example:

User enters: 432534.
Value of input: 43.

User enters: 12342342341234123412341235450596459863045896045.
Value of input: 12.

(Edited: to say 'digits' instead of 'bits')

Comment: Those aren't bits, they're digits.

Comment: What do you want to happen with the remaining digits? Should they just be thrown away? What if the user enters `-123`? Should that be `-1` or `-12`?

Comment: I've just edited the question.  Sorry, @chris, that your comment now seems irrelevant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the first two digits and form an integer:

```
int digit1 = std::cin.get() - '0';
int digit2 = std::cin.get() - '0';
int input = digit1 * 10 + digit2;
```

Then discard the rest of the input:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

To handle a negative sign, you could do something like this:

```
int input = 1;

int digit1 = std::cin.get();
if (digit1 == '-') {
    input = -1;
    digit1 = std::cin.get();
}

digit1 -= '0';
int digit2 = std::cin.get() - '0';
input *= (digit1 * 10) + digit2;
```

As commented below, this does not work if the user enters anything except two numbers as the first two characters. This is easy enough to check by reading and using `std::isdigit` to test. It's up to you to keep going or throw an error of some sort.

This also doesn't work if the user enters one digit only. If you need that to work as well, you can either read a whole string and use its size or check for EOF.

There is also no error checking on the input operations themselves, but there should be in real code.

Comment: is the order of evaluation assured?

Comment: Note this won't discard any leading whitespace, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @zch and BoB, True, I took this to mean the user is expected to enter at least two digits right off the bat. I'll add a note at least.

Comment: "I'll take '~~' burgers please!" =P (just being a pest; its the right idea, +1)

Answer (score 5):

I think `std::string` operations can get you home.

```
std::string inputstr;
cout << "Please enter how many burgers you'd like" << endl;
cin >> inputstr;
inputstr = inputstr.substr(0, 2);

int input    
input = std::stoi(inputstr);      // C++11
input = atoi(inputstr.cstr());    // pre-C++11
```

Documentation:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi

Comment: I recommend using `std::strtol` pre-C++11. It has the same error checking capabilities as `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned `fscanf`. While C++ purists may object, this requires substantially less code (and substantially better error checking) than `cin` in this case.

```
int res = 0;
std::cout << "Please enter how many burgers you'd like" << std::endl;
if (fscanf(stdin, "%02d", &res) != 1) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid Input" << std::endl;
}
int c;
do {
    c = fgetc(stdin);
} while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
std::cout << "Got " << res << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that this requires that `cin` be synced with `stdin` which is the default anyway

Answer (score 0):

Take `input` as string and convert the 1st two character as `int`

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string input ;

   std::cin>>input;
   std::stringstream iss(input.substr(0,2));
   int num;

   iss >> num;

   std::cout<<num;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
cin >> i;
while (i >= 100 || i <= -100) {
   i = i / 10;  // remove and ignore the last digit
}
```

This won't work for really large numbers, due to overflow in the integer.  I'm just including this as a very simple algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Read a string and extract the first 2 chars:

```
std::string input;
cout << "Please enter how many burgers you'd like" << endl;
cin >> input;
int first2;
if (input.size()>=1)
{
    if (input[0] == '-')
       std::cerr << "Negative num of burgers";
    else
       first2 = atoi(input.substr(0,2).c_str());
}
else
    std::cout << "Null number";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method will be easy to understand.

```
int input;
cout << "Please enter how many burgers you'd like" << endl;
cin >> input;

char cTemp[50];

itoa(input, cTemp, 10);

char cResult[3] = {cTemp[0], cTemp[1], '\0'};

int output = atoi(cResult);
```

Comment: Besides being too C for my taste, and not being readable, it has a nice buffer overrun. -1

Comment: @IInspectable, At the very least, there's not likely a buffer overrun unless sizeof(int) is huge.

Comment: @chris If you don't want `atoi` to access `cResult[2]` (3rd element) you will have to prevent that from happening. As it stands this is not what the code is doing. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable, Oh, that *is* one. I thought you meant the `itoa`, sorry.

Answer (score -3):

Let me answer the question by rewriting it for you:

> How do I read a string from the standard input and write the first 2 characters to the standard output?

Comment: And how does that answer the question?

Comment: @David It translates a non-trivial numeric problem into a string manipulation problem so trivial that anyone can solve it: `string input; cin >> input; istringstream iss(input.substr(0,2)); int result(0); iss>>result;`

Comment: And... *that* is what should have gone into the answer.

Comment: @David I'd like to disagree. Replicating trivial code did not answer this question. Translating the question did. If you believe that adding a call to `string::substr()` adds any significant value, feel free to edit this answer.